# Instantiated Text mesh pro game object appears with no opacaty

Tags: unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I am working on a game where I need to Instantiate TMP text as a gameobject (tried instantiating as TMP text but wouldn't appear in the list where I add the objects). I change the text value while instantiating and that works but even though the prefab text has max opacity the text appears with 0 opacity.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Is it a `TextMeshProUGUI`? In that case it would need to be instantiated under a UI Canvas

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to mention that it is instantiated under a UI canvas.

Comment: Are you instantiating from a prefab?

Comment: Yes I am instantiating from a prefab